# xquery function to convert a datetime value from EST to UCT based on the datetime value and not as per the current date

Tags: xquery

I am converting from EST to UTC. I need the result as below: If the dateTime passed is Feb-09-2017 11:30:00 then the UTC return should be Feb-09-2017 16:30:00 always irrespective of when I am executing the xquery. If I use the fn:adjust-dateTime-to-timezone then when I execute the xquery before the daylight saving time then the result is Feb-09-2017 16:30:00 (adds 5 hours which is correct) and however if I run the same query after the daylight saving time (ie after Mar 12) then the response becomes Feb-09-2017 15:30:00 (adds 4 hours).

Answer (score 1):

The XPath/XSLT/XQuery date/time system only knows about numerical timezone offsets, not about civil/geographical/political conventions. So it understands -05:00, but not EST. To do this conversion you need access to external information.

If you're in Saxon there's an extension function `saxon:in-summer-time(dateTime, civilTimeZone)` which tells you if you're in daylight savings time, for example `saxon:in-summer-time(current-dateTime(), 'America/New_York')` returns true, enabling you to adjust the displacements used when calling `adjust-dateTime()`.